# Containers - Failed to get host IPs

Tags: docker, networking, containers, datadog

I trying to run 3 containers and get the error for all of them.
I found the source code, but can't find the answer to why this is happening.
Also, tried to look at the internet and can't find anyone with the same error.

Source code:
https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/eb35254e9e13165b4148fc9280ef79e2d6bf8235/pkg/util/docker/containers.go

The error from /var/log/syslog:

> process-agent[30759]: 2019-12-11 08:58:17 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR |
>   (pkg/util/docker/containers.go:110 in ListContainers) | Failed to get
>   host IPs. Container XXXXX will be missing network info: %!s()

The containers running on the Host network.

Thanks

Comment: are you on VM ?

Comment: No, running on NUC

Comment: There's not really enough detail here for us to answer your question. How are you starting the containers? From the error, it looks like you're running them with `--net=host`. If that's true, what does the interface configuration on your host look like? Please update the question with additional information (do not leave it in comments).

Comment: With the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. e.g. with a container binding to port 80 with host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

The --net=host option is used to make the programs inside the container look like they are running on the host itself, from the perspective of the network. It allows the container greater network access than it can get.

Comment: #1 what kind of containers are you using?  #2 no one of them can start?

Comment: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/3796